# Slim (v3) Access Request in Group Function

Tags: php, slim

Let there be a [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com) (v3) group like:

```php
$app->group('/user/{user_id}', function(App $app) {

    // HERE

    $app->get('/stuff', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
         $userId = $request->getAttribute('user_id');
         // ... get stuff of user
    });

    $app->get('/otherstuff', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
         $userId = $request->getAttribute('user_id'); // repetition!
         // ... get other stuff of user
    });

});
```

Is there a way to access the `$request` (and therefore the URL param) in the group function, to avoid redundant repetitions in every function?

Comment: I think [middlewares](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/concepts/middleware.html) will help you achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `$request` object in the `group()` method via the container.

```
$req = $app->getContainer()->get('request');
```

But you'll get `NULL` when you use the `getAttribute()` method. In your case, the Request retrieved from the container should not be used since the state of the Request can be *altered* if necessary.

The [Request](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/request.html) and [Response](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/response.html) objects are immutable. The attributes can vary depending on when you get the Request object. The *finished* Request object will be handed over in your action at the end. So, use it in your action.

Yet still you can get the path and grab the URL param of `user_id`.

```
$path = $req->getUri()->getPath();
$user_id = explode('/', $path)[2];
```

Being said that, the `group()` method is intended to help you to organize routes into logical groups. If you want to DRY up your code, create a class with actions you need. For example:

```
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;

class UserController
{
    protected $container;
    protected $userId;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->userId = $this->user();
    }

    public function stuff(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        // Use $this->userId here
    }

    public function otherStuff(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        // Use $this->userId here
    }

    protected function user()
    {
        $path = $this->container->get('request')->getUri()->getPath();
        $parts = explode('/', $path);
        return $parts[2] ?? '';
    }
}
```

Then, update your routes:

```
$app->group('/user/{user_id}', function(App $app) {
    $app->get('/stuff', UserController::class . ':stuff');
    $app->get('/otherstuff', UserController::class . ':otherStuff');
});
```

Alternatively, you can get `$user_id` from the route parameters:

```
class UserController
{
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function stuff(Request $request, Response $response, array $args)
    {
        // Use $args['user_id'] here
    }

    public function otherStuff(Request $request, Response $response, array $args)
    {
        // Use $args['user_id'] here
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer the closures:

```
$app->group('/user/{user_id}', function(App $app) {
    $app->get('/stuff', function(Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
         // Use $args['user_id'] here
    });

    $app->get('/otherstuff', function(Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
         // Use $args['user_id'] here
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I should use classes instead of closures.